# Pascal Code For Voting Slip

Tags: pascal

```
PROGRAM VOTING_SLIP (INPUT,OUTPUT);

CONST

Array_size = 20;

VAR
Counter, Increment, i, j : Integer;
Found, full_name, District_ID : string;
DistrictArea : Array[1..20] of string;
DistrictID : Array[1..20] of string;

BEGIN

WRITELN('Please Populate District Area Array');
FOR i := 1 to 20 DO
READLN(DistrictArea[i]);

WRITELN('Input Values for District ID');
FOR j := 1 to 20 DO
READLN(DistrictID[i]);

WRITELN('Please Enter Voter Name');
READLN(full_name);

IF (full_name <> 'END') THEN DO
READLN(District_ID);
Increment := 1;
Counter := 0;
Found := 'FALSE';

WHILE(Found = 'FALSE') AND (Increment <= Array_size) DO
 IF (DistrictID[Increment] = District_ID) THEN
 Found := 'TRUE';
ELSE
 Increment := Increment + 1;

IF (Found = 'TRUE') THEN
 WRITELN (full_name,'you have been registered to vote in', 
 DistrictArea[Increment]);
 Counter := Counter + 1;
ELSE
 Writeln ('Error! Invalid District ID');
ELSE
 Writeln ('you have', Counter, 'registered voters. Goodbye!');
END.
```

The above code will not execute  the pas the 10th line. Compiler says:

```
1. 26 / 3 oneste~1.pas
 Error: Illegal expression
2. 26 / 3 oneste~1.pas
 Error: Illegal expression
3. 26 / 3 oneste~1.pas
 Fatal: Syntax error, ; expected but identifier READLN found
```

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: Note wrong index : `FOR j := 1 to 20 DO
READLN(DistrictID[i]);`

Comment: Error here: `IF (full_name <> 'END') THEN DO`. Remove `DO`.

Comment: thanks guys all these errors have been fixed as per your guidelines. please see updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you say line 10? The error message says line 26.

There is not supposed to be a DO after IF-THEN.

You should encompass some of your statements in BEGIN-END blocks.

You have superfluous semicolons before the keywords ELSE and END.

Near the end you have two ELSE clauses. What is that supposed to do?

Comment: By the way, I recommend indenting the code better, so one can see what is supposed to be under each IF or WHILE.

Comment: The code is supposed to allow entering values for a district Area and District ID in an array. then accept voter name, if end is entered then code close and display number of voters using counter variable, else it allows for district ID to be entered for that voter name. after this is done the code the district ID array to ensure its a correct district ID; if yes prints voter name and corresponding district area to screen, if no notifies that the district ID is invalid.

Comment: @TakeemLowe, those were retorical questions. You must decide what the program should do. P.S. I would recommend to always use full begin/end clauses.

Comment: Please see updated code and new compiler error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the updated code with respect to comments:

```
PROGRAM VOTING_SLIP (INPUT,OUTPUT);

uses crt;

CONST
 Array_size = 20;

VAR
 Counter, Increment, i, j : Integer;
 Found, full_name, District_ID : string;
 DistrictArea : Array[1..20] of string;
 DistrictID : Array[1..20] of string;

BEGIN

WRITELN('Please Populate District Area Array');
FOR i := 1 to 20 DO
 READLN(DistrictArea[i]);

 WRITELN('Input Values for District ID');
 FOR j := 1 to 20 DO
 READLN(DistrictID[j]);

 WRITELN('Please Enter Voter Name');

 READLN(full_name);

 IF (full_name <> 'END') THEN BEGIN
 READLN(District_ID);
 Increment := 1;
 Counter := 0;
 Found := 'FALSE';
 END

  WHILE (Found = 'FALSE') AND (Increment <= Array_size) DO BEGIN
   IF (DistrictID[Increment] = District_ID) THEN BEGIN
   Found := 'TRUE';
   END
   ELSE BEGIN
   Increment := Increment + 1;
   END
  END

  IF (Found = 'TRUE') THEN BEGIN
    WRITELN (full_name,'you have been registered to vote in', 
    DistrictArea[Increment]);
    Counter := Counter + 1;
  END
  ELSE BEGIN
   Writeln ('Error! Invalid District ID');
  END
 ELSE BEGIN
  Writeln ('you have', Counter, 'registered voters. Goodbye!');
 END
END.
```

New compiler Error: 
35 / 3 oneste~1.pas
 Fatal: Syntax error, ; expected but WHILE found

The code is supposed to allow entering values for a district Area and District ID in an array. then accept voter name, if end is entered then code close and display number of voters using counter variable, else it allows for district ID to be entered for that voter name. after this is done the code the district ID array to ensure its a correct district ID; if yes prints voter name and corresponding district area to screen, if no notifies that the district ID is invalid.

Comment: When it says ';' expected, you can try to simply insert a semicolon there.

Comment: followed your instruction going down then code inserting semicolons. 
    Now the error is: 54 / 2 oneste~1.pas
   Fatal: Syntax error, ; expected but ELSE found
and inserting a semicolon at the End directly above this Else statement is not solving the issue.

Comment: Remember I asked why you had two ELSE's in a row? You probably mean something by it, but that syntax is not allowed.

Comment: ok understand what you mean. The last and final else in the body of the code is supposed to be Else for the first if statement. So if END is entered in full_name then that else should execute terminating further entry and state how much voters were entered using counter.

Answer (score 0):

```
PROGRAM VOTING_SLIP (INPUT,OUTPUT);

uses crt;

CONST
 Array_size = 20;

VAR
 Counter, Increment, i, j, k : Integer;
 Found, full_name, District_ID : string;
 DistrictArea : Array[1..20] of string;
 DistrictID : Array[1..20] of string;

BEGIN

 WRITELN('Please Populate District Area Array');
 FOR i := 1 to 20 DO BEGIN
   READLN(DistrictArea[i]);
 END;

 WRITELN('Input Values for District ID');
 FOR j := 1 to 20 DO BEGIN
  READLN(DistrictID[j]);
 END;

 For k := 1 TO 10 DO BEGIN

  WRITELN('Please Enter Voter Name');

  READLN(full_name);

  IF (full_name <> 'END') THEN BEGIN
   WRITELN ('Please enter District ID');
   READLN(District_ID);
   Increment := 1;
   Counter := 0;
   Found := 'FALSE';
  END;

   WHILE (Found = 'FALSE') AND (Increment <= Array_size) DO BEGIN
    IF (DistrictID[Increment] = District_ID) THEN BEGIN
     Found := 'TRUE';
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
    Increment := Increment + 1;
    END
   END;

    IF (Found = 'TRUE') THEN BEGIN
     WRITELN (full_name,' - you have been registered to vote in - ', 
     DistrictArea[Increment]);
     Counter := Counter + 1;
     END
    ELSE BEGIN
     Writeln ('Error! Invalid District ID');
    END;

   IF (full_name = 'END') THEN BEGIN
    Writeln ('you have - ', Counter, '- registered voters. Goodbye!');
   END
  END;
END.
```

This is a final working code with the functionality I originally intended.
I figured it out the remaining issues and added some enhancements. A big thank you to everyone who assisted me.